# jQuery Selecting Checkbox In Specific Row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table in which I need to get the input type checkbox element from a specific row.
I tried selecting it like so (let's say I am interested in the first row)

```
$('tr :nth-child(1):checkbox')
```

yet I get ALL inputs from the table , not just from the row I need . 
Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
$('tr').eq(0).find(':checkbox').doSomething();
```

for example (zero-based).

Your code is wrong because you have space after `tr` and that means next selector is in child tree below table-row. Pseudo-selectors must be right after element they apply to, without the space, `$('input:checkbox')` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong. Try this:

```
$('tr:nth-child(1) :checkbox')
```

The pseudo-class `nth-child` must apply to the selector `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the use of .eq().

[jQuery .eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('tr').eq(0) //selects first tr
```